# Passing a php variable through from a selector to search database

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I'm working on a project for a class and I'm having trouble passing on a variable from a Chosen selector. I am passing on the $inst variable just fine, but the $focus variable is giving me this:

> Undefined index: chzn2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\results.php on line 20.

fyi: I have allowed for null in the database

Here is the code for the selectors.

```
    $sql = "SELECT institutionName, instID FROM institutions";
    $dropq = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo "<select data-placeholder='Select an Institution' name='chzn1' class='chzn-select' standard='true' style='width:250px;'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dropq)) {
        echo "<option></option><option value='" . $row['instID'] . "'>" . $row['institutionName'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";

    $sql1 = "SELECT orgFocus FROM communityOrgs";
    $dropq = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

        echo "<select data-placeholder='Select Focus Area' name='chzn2' class='chzn-select' multiple='true' style='width:250px;'>";
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($dropq)) {
        echo "<option></option>
                <option value='" . $row1['orgFocus'] . "'>" . $row1['orgFocus'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
```

Here is the code for the results

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
if(empty($_POST['chzn1']) && empty($_POST['chzn2'])){
    echo "Please enter at least one value!";
}
else if(!empty($_POST['chzn1']) || !empty($_POST['chzn2'])) {

// Grabbing variables from User Inputs
$inst = $_POST['chzn1'];
$focus = $_POST['chzn2'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM partnerships WHERE instID = '$inst' OR orgFocus = '$focus'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($queryResults > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<div class='results-container'>
            <h3>".$row['instName']."</h3>
            <p>".$row['orgName']."</p>
            <p>".$row['orgFocus']."</p>
            </div>";
    ;}
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests:

> Undefined index: chzn2

and according to your logic one out of the two values can be passed that leaves the ability for one to be unset so an error is thrown - as it should.

You need to do a check to see if either one of the `$_POST` keys exist separately and set their values respectively, either to what was passed or null.

**Example**

```
<?php
$chzn1 = null;
$chzn2 = null;

if (!empty($_POST['chzn1']))
    $chzn1 = $_POST['chzn1'];

if (!empty($_POST['chzn2']))
    $chzn1 = $_POST['chzn2'];
?>
```

Now they will both have default value so the error won't  be thrown.

**Note:** Seeing as you are using `mysqli_*` make use of prepared statements.

**Update #1**

Maybe due to a formatting error but you also have a floating semicolon `;`:

```
;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select` and `option` is not separated. As you are echoing separate make it combine.

```
 $row = "<select data-placeholder='Select Focus Area' name='chzn2' class='chzn-select' multiple='true' style='width:250px;'>";
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($dropq)) {
    $row .= "<option></option>
            <option value='" . $row1['orgFocus'] . "'>" . $row1['orgFocus'] . "</option>";
    }
    $row .= "</select>";
    echo $row;
```

Same for other select tag